# CPA-security proof of "l-padded RSA" encryption scheme

Tags: rsa, public-key, chosen-plaintext-attack

The 10.9 exercise from the Katz-Lindell textbook creates a lot of confusion, let me state it here. Consider the following experiment for an algorithm $A$ and a function $l$ with $l(n) \leq 2n-2$ for all $n$:

**The padded RSA experiment** $PAD_{A,GenRSA,l}(n)$:

1. $(N,e,d) \leftarrow GenRSA(1^n)$.
2. Give $N$, $e$ to $A$, who outputs a string $m \in \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$.
3. Choose random $y_0 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}^*_N$ and $r \leftarrow \{0,1\}^{||N||-l(n)-1}$, then set $y_1=[(r||m)^e \mod N]$.
4. Choose a random bit $b \leftarrow \{0,1\}$. Adversary $A$ is given $y_b$, and outputs a bit $b'$.
5. The output of the experiment is $1$ if $b'=b$, and $0$ otherwise.

The exercise asks to prove that if this $l-padded$ $RSA$ is hard relative to $GenRSA$, then this $PAD$ construction using $l$ is CPA-secure. Unfortunately my crypto teacher stated that "if $l(n) \leq 2n-2$ then this construction is conjectured secure but **there is no formal proof** based on standard RSA", which is precisely what the exercise is asking (if my understanding is correct). Please don't mark this question as a duplicate of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/proof-that-padded-rsa-is-cpa-secure) one, because it's not, note that I'm expliciting when $l(n) \leq 2n-2$ and not when $l(n)=O(\log n)$.

So, my question is: how should I procede, as the exercise task apparently contradicts the teacher's statement?

Comment: What is your question? There is no question mark in there. All I see are statements.

Comment: Sorry, my question is how should I procede, as the exercise task apparently contradicts the teacher's statement.

Comment: I don't know this for a fact, but notice that the problem says "prove that **if** ... is hard ... then ... is CPA-secure". Could it be that your professor is saying that there is no formal proof that the **if** statement is true? In other words, the problem is saying, assume X, now prove Y, while your profesor is saying that we don't really know if X is true? Therefore, there is no conflict.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Ok, so if I'll construct an adversary $A$, in this padded RSA experiment, in such a way that when it breaks the $PAD$ scheme then an adversary $A'$ will also break the $RSA$ $problem$, do you think this could be right way?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: I can't find any way of linking correctly the "RSA instance" - $(N,e,y)$ input to $A'$, where $y \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}^*_N$ - as a $PAD$ instance for $A$ in such a way that $A$ breaks the $PAD$ scheme when any encrypted message $m_i$ (the $i$th encryption query of $A$), the $r_i$ chosen during this encryption is the same as the $r^*$ used when encrypting the $A$'s message $m$. So, I want to consider the $y$ as the challenge ciphertext $y_1$, that is $(r^*||m)^e \mod N$, but then how can $A'$ generate the $y_0$ which should be randomly chosen from $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$?

Comment: I think you rather well answered your own question, @pa5h1nh0. However this may not be the place for followup questions. If you're stuck, try again, and if that doesn't work, ask a new question please.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I can't agree more with you about regarding "the place for followup questions". However, I would be more than happy and thankful if I could receive an answer as an **answer**, not as a comment, to my last comment question "... but then how can $A′$ generate the $y_0$ which should be randomly chosen from $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$?". Because having the solution to this would mean for me to have the solution to the reduction proof.